# Creating Chatroom in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, chatroom

I am trying to create a basic chat room just to enhance my programming and logical skills, but I can't figure out the functionality here.
The question which is bothering me is whether should I include database or not? 
(p.s: I don't want to record any chat sessions).
I tried on my own by using Application["variable"] to post messages like.

```
Application["Message"] = txtMessage.text;
txtDisplay.text = txtDisplay.text + Application["Message"].ToString();
```

I know this is not the correct way, there will be some limits to store huge amount of messages and can't be implemented on large traffic. I tested it on LAN and it worked fine, but need a proper way to complete my project.
Need a kick start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a proper solution of the chat utility (with latest technologies including ASP.net MVC), you should consider WebSockets [[http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/618032/Using-WebSocket-in-NET-Part]](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/618032/Using-WebSocket-in-NET-Part%5d) and SignalR [[http://www.asp.net/signalr]](http://www.asp.net/signalr%5d).